# Me aparece error en el doctype y no me permite cargar archivos locales debido a que aparece NOT ALLOWED TO LOAD LOCAL RESOURCE

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

La funcion de este codigo es que cuando insertes los datos que se escriben en un formulario se agrega una tarjeta la imagen se sube mediante un upload de html, se insertan todos los datos bien menos la imagen, aparece el alt y no encuentro el error. Anexo el script y el html del formulario para ver si me ayudan con el error se los agradecería.

Esto es un formulario que agrega cards desde un formulario, y se muestra de manera inmediata

[image: Es un formulario con un apartado de upload pero no se sube la imagen solo el texto.]

[image: QUIERO LOGRAR ALGO COMO ESTO PERO NO ME CARGA LA IMAGEN SOLO EL TEXTO]

El codigo con el que estoy mandando a llamar en js y html es el siguiente:

```
<!-- Aquí se agregarán las nuevas cards -->
                </div><br><br>
                
                <script>
                    let cardId = 1;
                
                    function agregarNuevaCard() {
                        // Obtener los valores ingresados por el usuario
                        const nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
                        const fecha = document.getElementById('fecha').value;
                        const pais = document.getElementById('pais').value;
                        const categoria = document.getElementById('categoria').value;
                        const imagenUrl = document.getElementById('imagen').value;
                
                        // Crear la nueva card con los datos ingresados
                        const nuevasCardsContainer = document.getElementById('nuevasCardsContainer');
                        const nuevaCard = document.createElement('div');
                        nuevaCard.classList.add('post');
                        nuevaCard.innerHTML = `
                            <div class="ctn-img">
                                <img src="${imagenUrl}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <h2>${nombre}</h2>
                            <span>${fecha}</span>
                            <ul class="ctn-tag">
                                <li>${pais}</li>
                                <li>${categoria}</li>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="#modalNueva"><button class="btn-leer">Leer más</button></a>
                            <a href="#elim1"><button class="btn-eliminar">Eliminar</button></a>
                            <a href="#edi1"><button class="btn-editar">Editar</button></a>
                        `;


HTML

<form id="formularioAgregar">
                <div>
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="pais">País:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pais" name="pais" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="categoria">Categoría:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="categoria" name="categoria" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="imagen">Imagen URL:</label>
                    <input type="file" id="imagen" name="imagen" required>
                </div>
                <button type="button" onclick="agregarNuevaCard()">Agregar evento</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Leyendo así rápido el problema el error podría ser porque no está permitido cargar elementos locales a una página web, por ejemplo si tienes una imagen en tu carpeta Imágenes no está permitido cargarlo por cuestiones de seguridad (imagina un script que obtenga los archivos locales cada vez que entres a el), puedes probar subiéndolo en algún lugar y copiando/pegando la url.